# CakePHP 3 validator - Unable to call method “” in “default” provider for upload field

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Here is my validator for the field article where pdf files should be uploaded:

```
 $validator
->add('article', [
    'rule' => [
        'extension' => [
            ['article', 'pdf'],
            'message' => 'Only  pdf!'
        ]
    ]
])
->notEmpty('article');
```

This gives an error:

> "Unable to call method "" in "default" provider for field "article""

How can I fix this to enable uploading only `pdf` files to the field article?

Comment: Instead of `['article', 'pdf']` it should be `['pdf']`

Comment: There was no need to delete your [original question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33449666/cakephp-3-validator-unable-to-call-method-in-default-provider-for-upload) and create a duplicate one. I'd still suggest to compare your code to [**the examples in the docs**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#creating-validators), the difference should be pretty obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the elements in your code is wrong.

Also worth a look: API Class Validation - [Extension](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Validation.Validation.html#_extension)

```
$validator
  ->add('article', [
    'extension' => [
      'rule' => [ 'extension', ['pdf'] ],
      'message' => 'Only PDF!'
    ]
  ])
  ->notEmpty('article', 'This field is required')
  ;
```

You should also check the [mimeType](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.Validation.Validation.html#_mimeType) to enhance security. Works similar, see also the example in the book in the chapter [conditional validation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#conditional-validation)